# JQuery Load() function

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnLoad").click(function(){
        $('#div1').load('test.txt', {}, fnLoad());
    });
});

function fnLoad()
{
    // How can I load the content of <div id="div1" /> into a variable here?
}
```

In fact, I want to work with the variable instead of div1.innerHTML.

Comment: I haven't tried it but wouldn't `var.load('test.txt',{});` work?

Comment: @Beneto, No, this type of call doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $.get for xhr request, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnLoad").click(function(){
        $.get('test.txt', fnLoad);
    });
});

function fnLoad(data)
{
    // Contents of test.txt should be in data argument here
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more, please?

Comment: jQuery's load method loads data (usually it is an HTML string) from a web server via AJAX request and then places it into the given matched element. 

If you don't need to place contents of test.txt inside #div1 element and just put it in some variable, you should better use $.get method of jquery. When the data is loaded, the `fnLoad` function will be called and it's first argument will be what you need. 

If you still need the contents of test.txt placed inside #div1 - you should use the sample provided by @JamWaffles above

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnLoad").click(function(){
        $('#div1').load('test.txt', {}, fnLoad));
    });
});

function fnLoad(result)
{
    // The variable `result` contains the response of the AJAX call.
}
```

This much like passing `result` into an anonymous function in the `.load()` call itself, but you've split the function out into it's own, named one. You need to pass a reference to `fnLoad()`. `result` will contain the response data. [The function prototype for `.load()` accepts 3 arguments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#example-1):

> `response, status, xhr`

You can map these to whatever variable names you like in `fnLoad()`.

Comment: This won't work, as you are passing the result of fnLoad call to function, it has to be `$('#div1').load('test.txt', {}, fnLoad)`